# Unknown issue displaying Mapbox GL JS map layers

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js web app (using Vue CLI) loading a Mapbox GL JS map, with a series of GeoJSON layers of various kinds (point, line, fill and fill-extrusion). However, the map is doing something very odd, which I have never seen in Mapbox maps before - and is difficult to explain - [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pungm.png) [(and another)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJMU7.png).

I feel like I must have done something to mess this up! I assumed it was caused by one of my additional layers, so I've tried removing all my additional layers, and the map seems to load fine, but then as soon as I zoom in or out, it reverts to this. Similarly, my app code automatically fits to the bounds of a layer when it loads - it flashes up with the 'normal' map styling briefly, then switches to this.

Interestingly, only my point layers seem to load correctly on the map (but when I use queryRenderedFeatures, it seems to correctly identify that the other layers are there).

Has anybody seen similar behaviour to this? Any thoughts on how to deal with it?!

Many thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced this issue loads of times! This generally happens when Vue tries to add reactivity to your mapbox map, so try and avoid binding your map to any data properties.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I had exposed the map object so I could read from it in another Vue component - I've now just exposed the small number of map functions I actually need to use, and it's working perfectly.